# MediumText and textArea in my form show.blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need your help because I am stuck... I should create a form with a text long.

In my function **up()**, I have this

```
$table->mediumText('resume');
```

In my page **create.blade.php**, the create works.

```
<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('resume') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="form-group-input-1">Résumé</label>
    <textarea name="resume" id="resume" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('resume')}}"/></textarea>
    {!! $errors->first('resume', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</fieldset>
```

However, I don't get the value (the text) on my page **show.blade.php**

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <label for="form-group-input-1">Résumé</label>
   <textarea name="resume" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" readonly="true" value="{{$livres->resume}}"/></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

If I don't use `textarea` but `input type=text` it works.

Do you have an idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="form-group-input-1">Résumé</label>
  <textarea name="resume" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" readonly="true" 
  value="{{$livres->resume}}"/></textarea>
 </fieldset>
```

use this

```
 <fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="form-group-input-1">Résumé</label>
  <textarea name="resume" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" readonly="true"/>{{$livres->resume}}</textarea>
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this (textarea does not get value):

```
<textarea name="resume" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" readonly="true"/>{{$livres->resume}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I always have the same problem. I have edited my first post with your code. I don't get the value... :-(

Comment: I can't see any change in your question code. Do you put your `{{$livres->resume}}`  BETWEEN open and close textarea tags?